# TS json compliant interface

Tags: typescript

I am having a very common issue, but the common answers on stackoverflow does not seem to be adapted in my case.

I have a bunch of objects that I need to manipulate, save and load as json files.
Say I have this interface:

```
type jsonValue = string | number | jsonValue[] | json | undefined;

interface json {
    [index: string]: jsonValue
}

interface I_Foo extends json {
    p1: string;
    p2: number;
}
```

I get this error:

> An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

How should I go about this issue ? I need to guarantee that all my interfaces respect the json format, so that the code does not prevent me from iterating on it, and to ensure I can stringify it, but I also need to specify a set interface for each object.

Edit: To clarify, what I need is a way to specify an interface with any number of properties, that can be iterated on, and whose properties have to be json compliant, that can then be implemented by a class.

Comment: I don't see the error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAVgzgewHYDUCGAbArtAvFOYAJwEskBzKAHyiSwFsAjCI62RVTHAbQF034yNliQATCADMyEUQG4AUPLLAWEtAGNogpFADe8qFG5lxADwBcBYmXK9L29NggKAvouWqN0AJIB9AGIICFAQpipicOxC+oZgAIyWhKQUCrEATJZ0TCyu8kA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAVgzgewHYDUCGAbArtAvFOYAJwEskBzKAHyiSwFsAjCI62RVTHAbQF02AUhwDyjGBADGwNliQATCADMyEOQG4AUBtCQoQ5KPFSo+AN4aoUbmQUAPAFwFiZcr0fxk6bBE0BfLTrQAApEEMDAJIogADwAKgB8JlCxUBC2wBDycFBkiixQAEpQAPxQptwA0jlIUADWECAIioVuhZW8vlCOSBAAbiwB4ND6SHHx+CFhEVFxUABkeiJiksDxg7oAkgD6AGIICEmLyNHmlmAAjI6EpBSaZwBM3QzMRH5rQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Holy shit yes ! thank you so much, I have been trying stuff for 2 days ! I have to read some doc on this infer keyword now.

Comment: @wonderflame Oh wait, I get this then: 
Class 'Foo' incorrectly implements interface '{ [x: string]: JsonValue; }'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Foo' .
Foo is a class that implements I_Foo

Comment: Infer is actually redundant here. Its purpose is to make the type more readable. Without it, we would see `{properties} & JsonObject`

Comment: It's not the OP focus though, but here is the [solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAVgzgewHYDUCGAbArtAvFOYAJwEskBzKAHyiSwFsAjCI62RVTHAbQF02AUhwDyjGBADGwNliQATCADMyEOQG4AUBtCQoQ5KPFSo+AN4aoUbmQUAPAFwFiZcr0fxk6bBE0BfTdrg0AAKRBDAwCSKIAA8ACoAfCZQcVAQtsAQ8nBQZIosUABKUAD8UKZWANK5SFAA1hAgCIpFbkXclfy+UI5IEABuLAE60PpI8Un4oeGR0fFQAGR6ImKSwAnDQVAAkgD6AGIICMljMeaWYACMjoSkFJoXAEy9DMxEfhtaEhhocDmHxxI9DAGAg9CywByewB5QsUDAWEYGBIEnh1ycd0o+AA5NiHvDEcjUWBnrRXgV8Jd8dZ5Okbs4KG0PJxvH4NEA). Should I write an answer?

Comment: What does adding this [index: string]: jsonValue; implies exactly ? I would like TS to warn me if I try to acces or add a property that does not exists in the class' interface

Comment: @wonderflame: Write an answer, explaining why the code works.

Comment: With an index signature, you'll be able to accept any string property in the foo instance. That's the whole point of it. If you want to have it in the type but not in the class you can remove the index signature like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8YRPN)

Comment: but then, I cannot iterate, right ? something like for(const key of foo) {foo[key] = ...} would throw an error. how do you shorten the link to a playground ? I cannot link the full url here

Answer (score 2):

Even though I was unable to reproduce the issue with the interfaces, the solution that would work is switching to types.

Modification of `JsonValue`:

```
type JsonValue = string | number | JsonValue[] | JsonObject | undefined;

type JsonObject = {
  [index: string]: JsonValue;
};
```

Utility type for more readable types:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R ? { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;
```

Then, we can create a type that accepts a generic parameter and returns an intersection of it with the `JsonObject`:

```
type Json<T> = Prettify<T & JsonObject>;

type I_Foo = {
  p1: string;
  p2: number;
};

type I_FooWithBase = Json<I_Foo>;
```

If you would create a class that implements `I_FooWithBase` you will have to add an index signature to the class as well:

```
class Foo implements I_FooWithBase {
  public p1: string = '';
  public p2: number = 1;
  [index: string]: JsonValue;
}
```

However, this way you can access any string key which might be irrelevant:

```
const a = new Foo();
a.dasd // no error
```

Instead, make the class implement the `I_Foo` which has no index signature:

```
class Foo implements I_Foo {
  public p1: string = '';
  public p2: number = 1;
}

const a = new Foo();
a.dasd // expected error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYDUCGAbArtAvFOYAJwEskBzKAHyiSwFsAjCI62RVTHAbQF034yAPKMAVhADGwNliQATCADMyEOQG4AUBtCR2wsZOn4A3hqhRuZBQA8AXAWJlyve4M7YImgL6bt4aAAKRBDAwCSKIAA8ACoAfFD40VAQ1sAQ8nBQZIosUABKUAD8UMYWANJZSFAA1hAgCIr5LvncZfxeUPZIEABuLL460G4x8fhBIWERMVAAZHpIIuJSsQP+UACSAPoAYggICSVmUGAAjPaEpBSa5mAATF0MzETeq7pbuwgA6iTAABYAQmg4Hh5pF3nsVloJBggZkPll6GAMBB6OlgJlwftTDcsIwMCQJMczg5LpR8ABycnXY64-GEu4PJi5fAnbxQ5CEKBoA7dADuUA+AAoAJSaNAAOjkQLkUAA9LLktZIFJVMkiEQEEQgA)

Comment: But then, the last code wouldn't allow me to iterate on Foo properties right ? [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8kBN)

Comment: Then you have to use the index signature. I don't think that you'll be able to restrict access by `.` and have iteration at the same time.

Comment: I see, thank you. I will try to find a way, if I find it I will post it here. In the meantime, thank you so much for the help !

Comment: You should request that in a separate question, since it is out of scope of this one