# TS Json compliant class with interface

Tags: typescript

This question is a follow up to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76450005/ts-json-compliant-interface/76450199?noredirect=1)
I need a way to use TS to describe a class that:

- Is json compliant, meaning it can be serialized
- Implements strictly a specified interface
- Has properties that can be iterated on

Here is an example

```
type jsonValue = string | number | jsonValue[] | JsonObject | undefined;

type JsonObject = {
  [index: string]: jsonValue;
};

interface I_Foo extends JsonObject {
  p1: string;
  p2: number;
};


class Foo implements I_Foo {
  public p1: string = '';
  public p2: number = 1;
}

const foo = new Foo();

for (const key in foo) {
  console.log(foo[key])
}
```

and here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAVgzgewHYDUCGAbArtAvFOYAJwEskBzKAHyiSwFsAjCI62RVTHAbQF02AUhwDyjGBADGwNliQATCADMyEOQG4AUBtCQoQ5KPFSo%20AN4aoUbmQUAPAFwFiZcr0fxk6bBE0BfTRpkwCyKaBLQAJIA%20gBiCAhQELbB8nB6ImKS0uaWYACMjoSkFJq5AEyOdEwsfgEaEhhocGlxCST0YBgQ9BBIwGnRrVA5UGBYjBgkEqMFTsWU%20ADki6Wj45PTYBW0DMys%20Hl%20WhLIhFCK8Sa0EADuUK0AFACUAResDydIZwDWECBQZHO8SewwsUE%20iC6ADoMAhyA8LghuL8QLwnhpfEA)

As you can see, there are 2 errors, and I am not sure how to fix each.

Edit: To clarify, what I want is to be able to say "this class needs to have exactly these properties (the interface), needs to be iterable (so that I can use a `for...in` on it), and can be serialized as json".

Comment: As `I_Foo` extends `JsonObject` so class `Foo` needs to define `JsonObject` property also

Comment: The error is that TS expects Foo to have the property `key: string]: any`, which I don't want to use. If I do so, TS will allow any property on Foo, meaning the I_Foo interface becomes useless.

Comment: @dododingo please make it more explicit that you don't want to be able to access through `.`, but make it possible to pass a string in `for in`

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting TypeScript's type system.

This error - "Class 'Foo' incorrectly implements interface 'I_Foo'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Foo'." - can only be fixed by adding an index signature to your class.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I'm looking for ?

Comment: No. This is just the way TS works.